# How to update the table using array of values in Laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I do have a two array's, I would like to update the Db based on that.

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => 1 ) )`//Id array

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [quantity] => 740 ) [1] => Array ( [quantity] => 705 ) )` //The values that I need to update based on the previous array.
Some thing like this,

```
    DB::table('stock')->where('id' , $id_array)->update($value_array);
```

How Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_array = array(
  ['name' => 1],
  ['name' => 2]
);

$value_array = array(
  ['quantity' => 740],
  ['quantity' => 705]
);

foreach($id_array as $key => $value) {
    DB::table('stock')->where('id' , $id_array[$key]['name'])->update( $value_array[$key]['quantity']);
}
```

Assuming both arrays are equal size, we can loop through the $id_array and use the key index value for the $value_array.